# Showing ADS in vuejs el

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As we know, if we put `<script>` tag in the "el" vuejs, there will showing an error.. It's make me can't put any ads in vue el

For example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
{{ message }}
<script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='//p31898.clksite.com/adServe/banners?tid=31898_118905_0'></script>
</div>
```

> - Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.

so is it impossible to put Ads in Vue el?

Comment: jquery doesn't work well with vue, totaly different concepts,jquery is obsolete, and was always awful anyway

Answer (score 1):

I just built a vue component that can load 's

I've used it to load ads from various companies like Chitika, Medianet, Propeller

Here's the repo:

https://github.com/TheDynomike/vue-script-component

Here's how to use it:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <VueScriptComponent script='<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Peekaboo!"); </script>'/>
    <div>
</template>

<script>
import VueScriptComponent from 'vue-script-component'

export default {
  ...
  components: {
    ...
    VueScriptComponent
  }
  ...
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible, because `el` option is used to specify the DOM to get compiled with Vue.js component. That's why your error says `Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI`. The job Vue.js compiler does is only mapping the things like data, computed methods, or things like them into your mounted component.

Only the way you can do is not including `<script>` tag within your target element.

```
<div>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
  <script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='//p31898.clksite.com/adServe/banners?tid=31898_118905_0'></script>
</div>
```

Comment: so, I make 2 area? 1 area only for Vue (for compiling data, components, etc) and other area to showing ads?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible sir, but I've an alternative that maybe can help you need to `split` your html elements.

First, use Vue.js for compiling data (like from database)

```
<div id="app">
  {{ data }}
</div>
```

then create html element for showing your Ads

```
<div id="ads-example">
  <script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='//p31898.clksite.com/adServe/banners?tid=31898_118905_0'></script>
</div>
```

and, the last create html element again for another Vue el after ads element. I hope it can help you :)

Comment: so, is the structure like this?
```<div id="vue1"></div>
<div id="ads-place"></div>
<div id="vue2"></div>```